# parseInt, string, numbers, javaScript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, parseint

I'm trying to figure out why var catAge is not seen as a number (As it's not string?) and they concatenate and returns 52 not 7? I'm a beginner and any help will be appreciated!

```
    var petAge = 5;
    var catAge = prompt("How old is your cat?");

          // Won't work as expected
          alert(catAge + 2);

          // Works as expected
          alert(parseInt(catAge) + 2);
```

Comment: `prompt()` returns a string, so `+` is concatenation, not addition.

Comment: [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) for prompt

Comment: Answer `five` instead of `5` and the reason should be obvious.

Comment: Didn't realise prompt() returns a string! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
let petAge = 5;
let catAge = prompt("How old is your cat?");

  alert(parseInt(catAge) + 2);
```

use the following code, because  **prompt** returns a String value. So that it performed the concatenation operation